# How to improve font rendering in Jedit?

Tags: linux, java, fonts, jedit

I have started using Jedit due to easy to set up custom language syntax and folding. It is looking good except the fact that the font rendering seems to be the worst among all the editors (at least on Linux) I used (Vim, Komodo, SublimeText). My eyes are super sensitive to aliasing, in fact it gets confusing for me when the font rendering is uneven across the board. Jedit also suffers from improper font spacing, I am guessing this is due to aliasing related issues.

I personally like to use bitmap fonts as much as possible and one of my fav is Terminus. No bitmap fonts listed in the settings. Also the ones that listed do not look good even with all the antialiasing features avail in Jedit.

At the moment I settled with Courier  which seems to look best in Jedit.

I would like to improve the type looks in Jedit as much as possible. So I tried different versions of Java, Open Jdk 6 and 7, Oracle Jdk 1.7.4 without much success. It did not make much difference for me.

I am looking for advice on improving font rendering, font recommendations and possible fixes for Jedit.

I am on Debian 7 64b, Xfce, Linux 3.13-1

thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? jEdit's font rendering on Windows is great. Ubunut 16? Awful...